# Delete node from Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am working on iterative delete function that deletes node from a linked list, I think that the code is supposed to work fine, it traverses through the list, finds the needed node, points the head to the next node and deletes the current, but when I test run it  I get infinite loop, could you please help me to pinpoint the error, here is the function:

```
typedef struct E_Type * List;
struct E_Type
{
  int data;
  struct E_Type* next;
};
```

the function:

```
 bool erase(List & l, int data){
 List head = l; 
 if (l != 0){
    for(List current = head; current; current = current->next){
    if ( current->data == data )
       head = current->next;
       delete current;
       return true;
     }
   }
 return false;
}
```

the test program:

```
int main()
{
  List l = 0;
  cout << boolalpha << l->data << "went well? "<< (insert(l,73)) << endl;
  cout << boolalpha << l->data << "went well? "<< (insert(l,24)) << endl;
  print(cout,l);
  cout << boolalpha << "Is deleted 24? "<<(erase(l,24)) << endl;    
  cout << boolalpha << "Is deleted 35? "<<(erase(l,35)) << endl;
  print(cout,l);
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

the insert:

```
bool insert(List & l, int data)
{   

    List current = l;
    while(current != 0) {
        if (current->data == data)
        return false;
       current = current->next;
    }

    if (l == 0 || l->data > data){
        List new_list = new E_Type;
        new_list->data = data;
        new_list->next = l;
        l = new_list;
    return true;
    }

    else if(l->data < data){
    insert(l->next, data);
    return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the type of `List`?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to paste the typedef, now it is there

Comment: I see no `{` after the second `if` statement in `erase`.  That looks unintentional; you have multiple statements indented after it.  Try enclosing those statements in braces.  (There are still errors, but that looks like it'd be a big problem.  Looks like it unconditionally deletes the first entry.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andreas Brinck already points out, you need to update the 'previous' link as well. However, you don't need a dedicated variable for this, just use a pointer to a pointer:

```
bool erase(List & l, int data){
  List *it = &l;
  while ( *it ) {
    if ( (*it)->data == data ) {
      List next = (*it)->next;
      delete *it;
      *it = next;
      return true;
     }
     it = &(*it)->next;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This also takes care of handling all the "special cases" such as deleting from an empty list, deleting the first element in the list or deleting the last element in the list.

Comment: thanks a lot, the poiner solution is great and now i now how to easily refer to prev node in other functions.

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep track of the previous node as well in your for loop and do something like:

```
prev->next = current->next;
delete current;
```

You'll also need to handle the case where the deleted element is the first element of the list, in this case you need to set `l` to `l->next`

```
 bool erase(List & l, int data){
 if (l != 0){
    for(List current = head, prev = 0; current; prev = current, current = current->next){
    if ( current->data == data )
    {
       if (prev)
       {
           prev->next = current->next;
       }
       else
       {
            l = current->next;
       }
       delete current;
       return true;

     }
   }
 return false;
}
```

Your first erase is probably creating a circular list right now.

Comment: How can I keep track of the previous node in this for loop, I also thought about that solution but have no idea how to implement prev node here.

Comment: Looks more like it's removing all the entries before the one being deleted.  (Since it's not actually deleting them, though, it's leaking memory.)

Comment: Yes.. how could i miss that, i should close the if statement inside the loop

Comment: @cHao Good catch, although it returns after deleting the first value.

Comment: yes it works now but deletes all the data before current, I will try with prev node now

Comment: Just a random thought: to make the special case of the first entry less of a special case, you could make the "head" point to an empty List (no real data), with its `next` pointing at the first actual entry.  In the `for` loop, instead of saying `current = head, prev = 0`, you say `prev = head, current = head->next`.  Wastes `sizeof(int)` bytes, but makes every deletion and insertion (even of the first entry) just a matter of setting pointers in a `List`.

Comment: You don't need the `prev` pointer at all if you just used pointers to pointers (see my answer). Doing so will also gracefully catch the boundary cases (deleting the first element, deleting the last element, deleting from an empty list).

Answer (score 0):

We may need to see your insert method as well.

Is it possible that

```
current == current->next
```

If so that could cause the infinite loop.