# How can I delete terms with zero coefficient in linkedlist?

Tags: c++

I add a node  to poly. If there already
is a node with the same exponent, then I sum the coefficient
to the existing coefficient. But when I run this code, output is +0.0x^7  +0.0x^5  +0.0x^4  +0.0x^3  at the end. I'm trying to delete terms with zero coefficient in the function.How can I do this ?

```
struct PolyNode {
    double coef;             
    int exp;                 
    struct PolyNode* next; 
};

PolyNode* AddNode(PolyNode *head, double coef, int exp) {
    PolyNode* node = new PolyNode();
    node->coef = coef;
    node->exp = exp;
    node->next = NULL;

    PolyNode** p = &head;
    while (*p != NULL && exp <= (*p)->exp) {
        p = &(*p)->next;
    }
    node->next = *p;
    *p = node;

    PolyNode* first = head;
    PolyNode* second = NULL;

    while (first != NULL && first->next != NULL) {
        second = first;
        first = first->next;
        if (second->exp == first->exp) {
            
            second->coef = second->coef + first->coef;
            second->next = first->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
} 

void main() {

    PolyNode* poly = NULL;
    printf("Initial poly: "); Print(poly);

    poly = AddNode(poly, -2, 5);
    printf("Adding -2x^5: "); Print(poly);

    poly = AddNode(poly, 4.4, 7);
    printf("Adding 4.4x^7: "); Print(poly);

    poly = AddNode(poly, 2, 3);
    printf("Adding 2x^3: "); Print(poly);

    poly = AddNode(poly, 1, 4);
    printf("Adding x^4: "); Print(poly);

    poly = AddNode(poly, 4, 4);
    printf("Adding 4x^4: "); Print(poly);

    poly = AddNode(poly, 2, 5);
    printf("Adding 2x^5: "); Print(poly);

    poly = AddNode(poly, -4.4, 7);
    printf("Adding -4.4x^7: "); Print(poly);

    poly = AddNode(poly, -2, 3);
    printf("Adding -2x^3: "); Print(poly);

    poly = AddNode(poly, -5, 4);
    printf("Adding -5x^4: "); Print(poly);

   system("pause")
}
```

Comment: First among tens if not hundreds of duplicate questions: [Delete node from Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840591/delete-node-from-linked-list) Please read [ask] and search StackOverflow before posting a question.

Comment: I don't see the part where you're trying to delete terms with zero coefficient. Where is that part?

Comment: My guess is that `PolyNode *head` is wrong and should have been `PolyNode **head`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we're keeping with the style you've established, then this should work.

```
    PolyNode** first = &head;
    PolyNode** second = NULL;

    while (*first != NULL && (*first)->next != NULL) {
        second = first;
        first = &(*first)->next;
        if ((*second)->exp == (*first)->exp) {
            
            (*second)->coef = (*second)->coef + (*first)->coef;
            (*second)->next = (*first)->next;
            if ((*second)->coef == 0)
                (*second) = (*second)->next;
        }
    }
```

I'd maybe recommend refactoring the function to improve readability. Here's a rough example that can definitely be improved.

```
PolyNode* AddNode(PolyNode *head, double coef, int exp) {
    PolyNode* node = new PolyNode();
    node->coef = coef;
    node->exp = exp;
    node->next = NULL;

    // If the list is empty, return node as head
    if (head == NULL)
        return node;
    // Checking the head node edge cases
    else if (head->exp == exp) {
        head->coef += coef;
        if (head->coef == 0)
            return head->next;
    }
    else if (head->exp < exp) {
        node->next = head;
        return node;
    }
    else {
        PolyNode* traverse = head;
        while (traverse != NULL) {
            // We've reached the end of the list
            if (traverse->next == NULL) {
                traverse->next = node;
                break;
            }
            // The next value is of the same exponent
            else if (traverse->next->exp == exp) {
                traverse->next->coef += coef;
                if (traverse->next->coef == 0)
                    traverse->next = traverse->next->next;
                break;
            }
            // The next node is of a lesser exponent
            else if (traverse->next->exp < exp) {
                node->next = traverse->next;
                traverse->next = node;
                break;
            }
            traverse = traverse->next;
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

Keep in mind this example doesn't manage the memory it allocates.